# Saving interactive pyplot figures

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I've made some pyplots with interactive check buttons for a project to some of my colleagues. The check buttons are made to show the same values, but from different sensors. I'd like to send the generated plots to my colleagues with functioning check buttons. However, if I save the file as JPG/PNG the functionality will be lost. Is there a way to send an interactive python figure with functioning check buttons to other people who are not python users and don't really know programming?

Code not super-relevant, but posted below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons
### FIGURE 1 ###

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l0, = ax.plot(df1[vel_avg1],df1[htc1],color = 'C0', marker = 'o', label = 'HTC-1')
l1, = ax.plot(df1[vel_avg2],df1[htc2],color = 'C0', marker = 'o',label = 'HTC-2')
l2, = ax.plot(x_th, y_th, color = 'r', marker = 'o', markersize=0,
              label = 'Theoretical heat transfer coefficient')

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)
ax.set_xlabel('Off-gas velocity (m/s)', fontsize = SMALL_SIZE)
ax.set_ylabel('Heat transfer coefficient (W/m2K)', fontsize = SMALL_SIZE)
lines1 = [l0, l1, l2]

# Make checkbuttons with all plotted lines with correct visibility
rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15])
labels1 = [str(line.get_label()) for line in lines1]
visibility1 = [line.get_visible() for line in lines1]
check1 = CheckButtons(rax, ('HTC-1','HTC-2'), visibility1)

def func(label):
    index = labels1.index(label)
    lines1[index].set_visible(not lines1[index].get_visible())
    plt.draw()

check1.on_clicked(func)

plt.suptitle('From ' + start_date + ' to ' + end_date)
plt.savefig('fig1.png')
plt.show()
```

Does seaborn perhaps have a functionality like this or any other library?

Comment: This is a good question. I found this: https://github.com/maartenbreddels/ipyvolume/issues/144 It looks like you can preserve interactivity in a Jupyter notebook.